# SQL: getting duplicate records with this query

Tags: sql, join

I have an app that has posts, tags, and a tag_ref link table. I want to query for posts that have a specific tag association.

The database structure is as follows:

**posts**

id

body

city_id

**tags_ref**

row_id

table

tag_id

**tags**

id

safe_tag

tag

So tags_ref is a link table between posts and tags.

After adding some tags to posts I'm now getting duplicate records in my queries.

Even with this query:

```
SELECT P.* FROM posts as P WHERE P.city_id = 2
```

Even though I'm not joining tables here and only looking for posts where the city_id field is set to 2 I'm still getting duplicate records only for records that have tags associated with them.

I've also tried:

```
DISTINCT (P.id), P.* FROM posts as P WHERE P.city_id = 2
```

I know there are only 7 rows in my posts table so I know duplicate records don't actually exist as I'm counting 7 unique posts.

Can anyone help me figure out where I've gone wrong?

**Database is MySQL**

Thanks,

Billy

Comment: how many post are you getting duplicated?

Comment: What does you query return now? Please post the actual (not simplified) query and the actual output.

Comment: This doesn't sound possible, can you send the table structure for posts, tags, along with some sample data that is getting duplicated.

Comment: This is weird, are you **sure** that you get duplicate records when you do a simple `SELECT` to your table?, as in duplicate Ids for the posts?. Do you have a primary key for the table posts?

Comment: Your tags_ref table contains a field row_id. is this column your foreign key refering table posts/column id? What columns do you use for primaryKey? Do you have identityColumns? Distinct always means the complete row - so distinct (P.id), p.* does not mean that p.id is unique! Please provide some more information.

Comment: Also, what does `row_id` in `tags_ref` refer to?

Comment: @Ass3mbler 4 posts are being duplicated. Only posts that have tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> DISTINCT (P.id), P.* FROM posts as P WHERE P.city_id = 2
> ```

Your DISTINCT here does nothing when some values in other fields (in P.*) differ. Try to query the whole table posts without a filter to see what you've really got there.